# laptop running arch abruptly switches off when ripping video files

Tags: arch-linux, video-encoding

Whenever I try to transcode a movie or a large video file, my laptop always switches off abruptly some time after the transcoding has begun. I initially thought that this had something to do with my DVD drive but even when I tried converting videos from a hard drive, the problem remained. I've switched from Handbrake to VLC and still the problem remains.

When I opened System Monitor when the converting was going on, the CPU usage is around 100%. Is this a hardware problem or is it something wrong with the software?

Comment: Does the coding start and then it dies in the middle or does it get part way then fail?

Comment: @Caleb- part way and then fail

Comment: Thanks ... you might want to edit that bit of information into the question because it makes a difference. Also, does it really "switch off" or does it die and start to boot again? The "switch off" is what makes me think it's a hardware problem, dying and rebooting is often software.

Comment: It switches off and doesn't boot again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest that this is probably a hardware problem, most likely a CPU overheat issue. You might be able to prove this by running some other kind of stress test or checking your BIOS for what the warning and critical levels are and making sure their is an audible warning at a lower temp than the critical shut off level.

Comment: @Caleb- can I set-up an audible warning using BIOS?

Comment: @SamratManSingh: It depends on your BIOS, but many do have the option of an audible warning. Usually this would be set a few degrees below the critical temp where the BIOS shuts it off.